# Django - best way to replace custom image tag in textfield by imagefield

Tags: python, html, django

What is best way to replace custom "tag" (for example [IMG]image_name[/IMG]) with image url what exist in model as imagefield? For example:

```
class ImageResource(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Name')
   img = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Image')

class Post(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(verbose_name='Title')
   text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Text')
   images = models.ManyToManyField(ImageResource,verbose_name="Images")
```

DetailView to display template like this:

```
{{ object.text }}
```

I will replace all [IMG]name[/IMG] in object.text  to html img code who has src = images.url when images.name == name only. 
I don't want use wysiwyg editor. I don't know what is best place to do this - on model, view (what function?) or in specific filter?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your needs, you can use it in the templatetags if you only want to show the images in the template. But, you can also process it at the views. Here is an example templatetags to find the markdown images.

Regex [demo](http://www.pyregex.com/?id=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%3D%3D)

```
@register.filter
def markdown_find_images(markdown_text):
    """
    return list of image urls inside `markdown_text`.
    :param `markdown_text` is markdown text to find.
    example markdown text:
        Hello ![title](/path/to/image.png)
    provides for:
        jpeg|jpg|png|gif
    usage:
        {{ field_name|markdown_find_images }}
    example:
        {{ post.description|markdown_find_images }}
    """
    regex = r"[^(\s]+\.(?:jpeg|jpg|png|gif)(?=\))"
    return re.findall(regex, markdown_text)
```

In your case, [demo](http://www.pyregex.com/?id=eyJyZWdleCI6IlxcW2ltZ1xcXSguKz8pXFxbXFwvaW1nXFxdIiwiZmxhZ3MiOjAsIm1hdGNoX3R5cGUiOiJmaW5kYWxsIiwidGVzdF9zdHJpbmciOiJbaW1nXS9tZWRpYS9pbWFnZXMvdXBsb2Fkcy8yMDE3LzAxLzA3LzM2Y2I1NmNjMjQtTW90ZWwtd2Vic2l0ZTEuanBnWy9pbWddIG1kYW1kYSBtc2FtYXMgc21hbWFzIFtpbWddL21lZGlhL2ltYWdlcy91cGxvYWRzLzIwMTcvMDEvMDcvMzZjYjU2Y2MyNC1Nb3RlbC13ZWJzaXRlMS5qcGdbL2ltZ11cblxuW14oXFxzXStcXC4oPzpqcGVnfGpwZ3xwbmd8Z2lmKSg%2FPVxcKSlcblxuIDpncmluOiA6YW5ncnk6IDpwb29wOiBcblxuPiBtZG1hbWRhbWRcblxuLS0tLS0tLS0tLVxuXG5tZGFtbWRhICoqbWRhbWRhbSoqXG5cbltpbWddL21lZGlhL2ltYWdlcy91cGxvYWRzLzIwMTcvMDEvMDcvZmQxODdiNGE1Mi1mdWxsc2NyZWVuLWNvdmVyMS5qcGdbL2ltZ10ifQ%3D%3D):

```
@register.filter
def find_images(plain_text):
    """
    return list of image urls inside `markdown_text`.
    :param `markdown_text` is markdown text to find.
    example markdown text:
        Hello [img]/path/to/image.png[/img]
    provides for:
        jpeg|jpg|png|gif
    usage:
        {{ field_name|find_images }}
    example:
        {{ post.description|find_images }}
    """
    regex = r"\[img\](.+?)\[\/img\]"
    return re.findall(regex, plain_text)
```

Comment: I will not include url in text field. I will dynamically get url by image name what are linked to Post model (only this grup). I thing make query in filter is bad way.